# Integrating Stripe with Laravel using Cashier

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Laravel 5.

I have followed the steps from [Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/billing#subscribing-to-a-plan).  All is working fine apart from creating invoices.

**1. Generating Invoice**

This  `$invoice = $user->invoices();` works

But when after passing it to view, using any of these

```
{{ $invoice->id }} 

{{ $invoice->dateString() }}

{{ $invoice->dollars()}}
```

Returns this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

2. Downloading Invoice

And this command:

```
return $user->downloadInvoice($invoice->id, [
    'vendor'  => 'Your Company',
    'product' => 'Your Product',
]);
```

also returns same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a syntax error.
Follow this:

```
$invoices = $user->invoices()->get();
or 
$invoices = $user->invoices;
foreach($invoices as invoice){
   // do stuff
}
```

or

```
$invoice = $user->invoices()->first();
```

Comment: `$invoices = $user->invoices()` works just fine.  and what you are suggesting produce an error.

Comment: Give more informations about this error. Post all laravel debug infos